# Create tables and cell alignment in itext

Tags: itext

I want to create a table something like this
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y41D.png)

I tried a lot and I am new to this itext pdf in java. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you give an example of your code that isn't working?  Please take a look at the help center about how to ask a question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, @andorov is right. You say *"I tried a lot"*, so it shouldn't be difficult for you to show *what* you've tried and *why it's not working.* Right now, the readers on StackOverflow don't have a clue about what you're asking. There are plenty of [table examples](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables) and there's a [free ebook](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) with two chapters about tables. I'll vote to close the question because it's not clear.

Comment: @reka Please read this article to find out what you're doing wrong: http://blog.safedk.com/technology/technologythe-hitchhikers-guide-to-stackoverflow/